# Change count of rows by vanila js

Tags: javascript

Here we have a `textarea` in html file

```
<textarea class="form-control" onClick="do_resize(this)" rows="10" 
cols="150" id ="textvalue" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 
0px; height: 316px;">some text </textarea>
```

above in head I have next kind of string :

```
function do_resize(textbox) {
    var maxrows=50;
    var txt=textbox.value;
    var cols=textbox.cols;

    var arraytxt=txt.split('\n');
    var rows=arraytxt.length;

    for (i=0;i<arraytxt.length;i++){
        rows+=parseInt(arraytxt[i].length/cols);
    }
    if (rows>maxrows) {
        document.getElementById("textvalue").rows = maxrows
    }else{
        document.getElementById("textvalue").rows = rows
    }
}
```

When I click on text area of y `textrea` box don't changes .. I can't undestand why . Who can help me with ?

I want to get this one : 
[image]

but I have got this one all the time :

[image]

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: The if-clause does not do anything since rows = rows anyway?

Comment: what do you want ? change `row` on click ?

Comment: your if block doesn't have sense

Comment: See above , I've added some additional information

Comment: Remove height from the style and make sure the function is declared in the body

Comment: Your current code works perfectly if you remove the height CSS from the textarea, which is overriding the "rows" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the height of the inline style. I suggest using another event instead of click ( In my example I use [Input Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) -
 the DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of the textarea element is changed)

```js
function do_resize(textbox) {
    var maxrows=50;
    var txt=textbox.value;
    var cols=textbox.cols;

    var arraytxt=txt.split('\n');
    var rows=arraytxt.length;
    for (i=0;i<arraytxt.length;i++){
        rows+=parseInt(arraytxt[i].length/cols);
    }
    if (rows>maxrows) {
        document.getElementById("textvalue").rows = maxrows
    }else{
        document.getElementById("textvalue").rows = rows
    }
}
document.getElementById("textvalue").addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    do_resize(this);
});
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" 
cols="150" id ="textvalue" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 
0px;">some text </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: https://plnkr.co/edit/teZXdtA55JqZq9v0umdD?p=preview

For reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<textarea class="form-control" onkeyup="do_resize(this)" rows="2" cols="15" id ="textvalue">some text </textarea>
<script>
function do_resize(textbox) {
    var maxrows=50;
    var txt=textbox.value;
    var cols=textbox.cols;

    var arraytxt=txt.split('\n');
    var rows=arraytxt.length;

    console.log(arraytxt)
    for (i=0;i<arraytxt.length;i++){
        rows+=parseInt(arraytxt[i].length/cols);
    }
    if (rows>maxrows) {
        document.getElementById("textvalue").rows = maxrows
    }else{
        document.getElementById("textvalue").rows = rows
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```